# Shortcut to open a source file on Firefox Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am used to google chrome devtools (F12) and `ctrl + o` to search for a specific loaded source file.

I am currently using Firebug on Firefox and need to search a file. Is there a shortcut to do that? what is the best way?

Any help will be very appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard shortcut, but you can search for the script by opening the [script location menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu) and then type the name of the script.

[image: Script location menu in Firebug]